# Проверка на аргументы js

Tags: javascript, telegram, бот

Всем привет. Делаю тут телеграмм бота, и уже столкнулся с проблемой.. Я хочу сделать проверку на аргументы. Допустим, если человек пишет /buy, то ему пишет сообщение "a", если пишет /buy 1 - "b", если пишет /buy 2 - "c". Как это реализовать? Вот мой код:

```
bot.onText(/\/buy (.+)/, (msg, match) => {
    const chatId = msg.chat.id;
    if(match[1] == 0) {
        return bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Выберите, что вы хотите купить?\n/buy hours\n/buy graphic');
    }
    if(match[1] == "Буст часов") {
        return bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Hours');
    }    
    if(match[1] == "Дизайн") {
        return bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Graphic');
    }
});
```